# 2-norm of transpose proof

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I don't understand the proof of ‖x‖<sub>2</sub>=‖x<sup>T</sup>‖<sub>2</sub>.

I know you can use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and that you can prove it by first showing ‖x<sup>T</sup>‖<sub>2</sub> ⩽ ‖x‖<sub>2</sub> and then ‖x‖<sub>2</sub> ⩽ ‖x<sup>T</sup>‖<sub>2</sub>. I get proving both inequalities implies that ‖x‖<sub>2</sub>=‖x<sup>T</sup>‖<sub>2</sub>.

Though I don't get how the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is used to proves this. I would really appreciate getting a step by step on how you get to it, because I simply don't understand.

Comment: @user1551 yes it is

Comment: @user1551 a vector and from my understanding ‖xT‖2 uses the matrix norm right?

Comment: Most likely. It could mean the Euclidean norm, but then the problem statement would be trivial.

Comment: @user1551 ok, I just don't see how ‖x‖2 ⩽ ‖xT‖2. I'm having trouble making that connection

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we should understand exactly what the definition of $\|x^T\|_2$ is in this context. Whereas $\|x\|_2$ is simply the Euclidean norm of $x$, $\|x^T\|_2$ refers to the "operator norm" or "induced norm" of the matrix $x^T$. That is,
$$
\|x^T\|_2 = \max_{\|y\|_2 = 1} \|x^Ty\|_2 = \max_{\|y\|_2 = 1} |x^Ty|
$$
(see note below for $\|x^Ty\|_2$ vs $|x^Ty|$). The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality tells us that for any particular $y$ with $\|y\|_2 = 1$, we have
$$
|x^Ty|_2 \leq \|x\|_2\,\|y\|_2 = \|x\|_2 \cdot 1 = \|x\|_2.
$$
It follows that the maximum $\max_{\|y\|_2 = 1} |x^Ty|$ that we are interested in is at most equal to $\|x\|_2$. That is, $\|x^T\|_2 \leq \|x\|_2$.

As for the other direction of the inequality, I'm not sure how one can get this by using Cauchy-Schwarz again. One approach is simply to note that there is a unit vector $y$ such that $|x^Ty| = \|x\|_2$, meaning that $\max_{\|y\|_2 = 1} |x^Ty| \geq \|x\|_2$. To that end, we can consider $y = x/\|x\|_2$, and find that
$$
|x^Ty| = \frac{x^Tx}{\|x\|_2} = \frac{\|x\|_2^2}{\|x\|_2} = \|x\|_2.
$$
So, we can indeed conclude that $\|x^T\|_2 = \|x\|_2$.

---

**Note:** In the expression $\|x^Ty\|_2$, $x^Ty$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^1$ corresponding to the linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^1$ that is encoded by $x$. In the expression $|x^Ty|$, we are considering the single entry of this entry of this vector as a number and taking the absolute value of this number. Whether these are meaningfully distinct is a matter of philosophy.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can see how you got there. Would the same or similar be with the other inequality, ‖x‖2 ⩽ ‖xT‖2? I get the use of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the other and it finally makes sense, how should I proceed with the other inequality?

Comment: @myapepe See my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit ambiguous, as $\|\cdot\|_2$ may denote the Euclidean norm of a row/column vector or the induced $2$-norm of a $1\times n$ or $n\times 1$ matrix. Anyway, for clarity, let us denote the Euclidean norm by $\|\cdot\|_E$ and the induced $2$-norm by $\|\cdot\|_2$. Now let $x$ be a column vector. We actually have
$$
\|x^T\|_E\stackrel{(1)}{=}\|x\|_E\stackrel{(2)}{=}\|x\|_2\stackrel{(3)}{=}\|x^T\|_2.
$$
So, the statement in your question is correct, regardless of whether the notation $\|\cdot\|_2$ in your question is interpreted as the Euclidean norm or induced $2$-norm.

Equality $(1)$ is trivial and its proof is omitted here. Equality $(2)$ is almost trivial:
$$
\|x\|_2
=\max_{u\in\mathbb R^1,\ \|u\|_E=1}\|xu\|_E
=\max_{u=\pm1}\|xu\|_E
=\max_{u=\pm1}\|x\|_E
=\|x\|_E.
$$
Equality $(3)$ is a special case of a more general fact: for any $m\times n$ real matrix $A$, we have $\|A\|_2=\|A^T\|_2$. Here is the proof. First, observe that for any vector $w\in\mathbb R^m$, we have
$$
\|w\|_E=\max_{v\in\mathbb R^m,\ \|v\|_E=1}\langle v,w\rangle
$$
where the maximum occurs when $v$ is a unit vector point in the same direction as $w$. Now, let $u\in\mathbb R^n$ be the unit vector such that $\|A\|_2=\|Au\|_E$. If we take $w=Au$ in our previous observation, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\|A\|_2
=\|Au\|_E
=\max_{v\in\mathbb R^m,\ \|v\|_E=1}\langle v,Au\rangle
=\max_{v\in\mathbb R^m,\ \|v\|_E=1}\langle A^Tv,u\rangle\\
&\le\max_{v\in\mathbb R^m,\ \|v\|_E=1}\|A^Tv\|_E\|u\|_E
=\max_{v\in\mathbb R^m,\ \|v\|_E=1}\|A^Tv\|_E
=\|A^T\|_2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $\|A\|_2\le\|A^T\|_2$. By interchanging the roles of $A$ and $A^T$ in the argument above, we also obtain $\|A^T\|_2\le\|A\|_2$. Hence $\|A\|_2=\|A^T\|_2$.